# Como fazer para que ao submeter um form dentro de um iframe, a página que tem o iframe seja redirecionada?

Tags: php, javascript, html

> Estou criando uma página que funciona assim:
>
> A pessoa acessa uma página de cadastro, e dentro dessa página há um `iframe` com o formulário para o cadastro. Quando uma pessoa clica dentro do `iframe` em **cadastrar** ele redireciona para outra página que eu criei. Só que a nova página aparece dentro do `iframe`, e eu quero a página que contém o `iframe` seja redirecionada para `sucesso.html`.

Eu já tentei utilizar algo como `target=""`:

```
<form id="form1" target="_self" method="post" action="concluido.php">
```

Porém continuou do mesmo jeito.

#### Como fazer para que a janela seja redirecionada e não o conteúdo do iframe?

Comment: Testa com `target="_blank"`, senão podes fazer com JS no `onsubmit` abrir uma nova janela.

Comment: Eu não quero que abra em uma nova janela, eu quero que quando clicar DENTRO DO IFRAME em Cadastrar, a página que tem o iframe seja redirecionada para sucesso.html

Answer (score 2):

Se voce deseja abrir uma página nova, você pode colocar uma instrução na sua página contida no iframe para que quando concluir a recepção do PHP ele faça uma chamada js:

```
<script>
    window.open("suaPagina.php");
</script>
```

Caso deseje atualizar a página ao submit do formulário pode fazer assim:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" target="_blank"></form>
```

Refatorando aqui:
 Se deseja que o parent(pagina pai)seja atualizada toda, após o submit, você pode fazer em php adicionando um head após a manipulação do post:

```
<?php    
    header('Localização: suaPagina.php');    
?>
```

Pode fazer escrevendo um js após a manipulação:

```
<script>
    window.location = "suaPagina.php";

</script>
```

Ou pode usar a tag do formulário, submetendo toda a tela:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" target="_parent"></form>
```

Comment: Eu não quero que abra em uma nova janela, eu quero que quando clicar DENTRO DO IFRAME em Cadastrar, a página que tem o iframe seja redirecionada para sucesso.html

Comment: Editado lá.. havia começado escrever a resposta para atualizar o parent, mas quando li o título anterior `Abrir uma nova página`, mudei o conteúdo da resposta... Espero que atenda...

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar `target="_parent"` se tiveres um link que ao ser clicado deve abrir na página que contem o iFrame.

Se queres abrir um `url` especifico na página que contem a iFrame podes usar `window.parent.location` assim, por exemplo:

```
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault;
  window.parent-location = this.href;
});
```

#### Exemplo [online aqui](https://rawgit.com/SergioCrisostomo/version-files/master/SOpt_iframe.html)

Comment: Como ficaria para adaptar em:
`<input name="avanca" type="submit" id="btn" value="Cadastrar" style="
    position: relative;
    left: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
">`

Comment: @AlexandreLopes onde está a informação do  `url`? se for a da `<form>` podes usar `target="_parent"` na form.